# error computing area of a closed space in a force layout using d3js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a graph which I've laid out using force layout. Basically i want to color the area contained within the cycles in the graph. Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sayush/QK5Wq/).

I was trying to paint the cycles when the force layout stabilized.

```
force.on("tick",function(){
    // ... I update the position of nodes and the links

    if(force.alpha() < 0.006){
        force.stop();

        // I dont know if there's an easier way of doing this

        var xnodes = [];
        force.nodes().forEach(function(d){ 
        xnodes.push([d.x, d.y]);
        }); 

        // I tried creating a path and filling with with green
        vis.select("path.area")
            .data([xnodes])
            .enter().append("path")
            .style("fill", "#00ff00")
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("svg:d", d3.svg.area());
    }
});
```

When i run it in chrome, the debugger shows that it does create a path but the area of the path is 0px x 0px. I'm really confused with this. I even tried setting the array manually. I get the same error.

```
    var ynodes = [[352.3554660996234,304.3361316660001],[449.88953454311286,313.14153937680953],
[392.0458559272036,389.6656922220398],[352.3554660996234,304.3361316660001]];
    vis.select("path.area")
        .data([ynodes])
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", "#00ff00")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("svg:d", d3.svg.area());
```

However when i put this code in a blank html file (after you include the necessary libraries) it works fine. It does draw a path and fills it with green. I'm really confused here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The "code" link points to a fiddle with no javascript.

Comment: Sorry for that. Its up now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, it is not. You have to click "update" on jsfiddle and to copy paste the new url (something like adding /2 in the end depending on the version number)